Serious delays in Keras before training the neural network
I'm creating a NN that has 2 levels.
At the first level, there are several small neural networks that should have a good generalizing ability for the data being fed to them. At the second level there is a generalizing network.
neural network diagram
The problem is the program waits a very long time  before starting training (does something, probably converts) when I pass list of numpy. When I make one first-level NN (even a very large one) and give it only numpy, it immediately starts training. As soon as the list appears, it may take a few minutes to think (depending on the number of input neurons).
Reshape and attempts to make numpy of numpy lead to errors like “Data cardinality is ambiguous” or “model expects ... input(s), but it received ... input tensors…”.
How do I send the input data correctly?
Program to prepare base data-file.
import random

sTfx = "./input_X.csv"
sTfy = "./input_Y.csv"

fFTx = open(sTfx,"w")
fFTy = open(sTfy,"w")

iRN = 1844
iCN = 4420

for iRow in range(iRN):
    fFTx.write(str(random.randrange(0,1))+"\n")
    for iCol in range(iCN):
        sD = str(random.randrange(0,1))
        fFTy.write(sD)
        if (iCol!=iCN-1):
            fFTy.write(";")
        else:
            fFTy.write("\n")
        
fFTx.close()
fFTy.close()
        

Programm to split data (to make it easier to upload them to the Neural Network later)
import sys
import os



def get_col_nums(sFileName):
    fF = open(sFileName,"r")
    arrT = fF.readline().split(";")
    fF.close()
    return len(arrT)


def delim(sFileName,iNumOfArr,iDigs):
    
    sBaseOtpName = sFileName.split(".")[0]
    
    arr_F = []
    for i in range(iNumOfArr):
        arr_F.append(open("./TEST_DATA/"+sBaseOtpName+"_"+str(i)+".csv","w"))
            
    fF = open(sFileName,"r")
    for s in fF:
        arrT = s.rstrip().split(";")
        iCnt = 0
        iFNum = 0
        for sIt in arrT:
            arr_F[iFNum].write(sIt)
            iCnt += 1
            if (iCnt%iDigs==0):
                arr_F[iFNum].write("\n")
                iFNum += 1
            else:
                arr_F[iFNum].write(";")
    fF.close()
    
    for fF in arr_F:
        fF.close()
    
    
sDir = "./TEST_DATA"    

if not os.path.exists(sDir):
    os.makedirs(sDir)

sCfy = "input_Y.csv"


iDigs = 13

iColNum = get_col_nums(sCfy)
print(iColNum," <- iColNum")

iNumOfArr = iColNum//iDigs
print(iNumOfArr," <- iNumOfArr")

delim(sCfy,iNumOfArr,iDigs)


A program with a single neural network at the first level. The number of input neurons is 4420. It works fast.

import random
import sys
import os
import numpy as np

from keras.models import Model  
from keras import initializers 
from keras import callbacks
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Dropout, concatenate 
import tensorflow as tf


sTfy = "input_Y.csv"
sTfx = "input_X.csv"
                
Y_arr_train = np.loadtxt(sTfy,delimiter=";",dtype=float)
X_arr_train = np.loadtxt(sTfx,delimiter=";",dtype=float) 
 
    
print(len(Y_arr_train)," <- len(Y_arr_train)")    
print(len(Y_arr_train[0])," <- len(Y_arr_train[0])")    

print(Y_arr_train.shape," <- Y_arr_train.shape")
print(X_arr_train.shape," <- X_arr_train.shape")

i_hidden_layers_num = 2 
iNumOfTopNN = 1 # One NN on the first layer
i_nn_num = 1000 # Number of neurons for NN on the first layer

i_nn_2_num = 10


arr_input_layers = []
arr_of_arr_hidden_layers = []
arr_output_layers = []



# Makes inputs for first level of NN 
for i in range(iNumOfTopNN): 
    arr_input_layers.append(Input(shape=(len(Y_arr_train[0]),)))   
    
# Makes Dense layer for first level of NN 
for i in range(iNumOfTopNN): 
    arr_t = []
    for ii in range(i_hidden_layers_num):
        if (ii==0):
            arr_t.append(Dense(i_nn_num, activation='relu')(arr_input_layers[i]))
        else:
            arr_t.append(Dense(i_nn_num, activation='relu')(arr_t[ii-1])) 
    arr_of_arr_hidden_layers.append(arr_t)
    
# Makes outputs for first level of NN 
for i in range(iNumOfTopNN):
    arr_output_layers.append(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(arr_of_arr_hidden_layers[i][len(arr_of_arr_hidden_layers[i])-1]))


# Concatenate outputs
combined_outputs = concatenate(arr_output_layers)

# Makes NN of 2nd level 
hidden_layer2 = Dense(i_nn_2_num, activation='relu')(combined_outputs)
output_layer2 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(hidden_layer2)

model = Model(inputs=arr_input_layers, outputs=output_layer2)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# model.summary()
print("Fit")
hist = model.fit(Y_arr_train, X_arr_train, batch_size=len(Y_arr_train[0]), epochs=20, verbose=1)


A program with 340 neural networks at the first level. The number of input neurons is 4420. It thinks for a very long time before starting training.
import random
import sys
import os
import numpy as np

from keras.models import Model  
from keras import initializers 
from keras import callbacks
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Dropout, concatenate 
import tensorflow as tf


sTfx = "input_X.csv"

i_hidden_layers_num = 2 
iNumOfTopNN = 340 # One NN on the first layer
i_nn_num = 4 # Number of neurons for NN on the first layer
i_nn_2_num = 10

Y_arr_train = []
for i in range(iNumOfTopNN):
    Y_arr_train.append(np.loadtxt("./TEST_DATA/input_Y_"+str(i)+".csv",delimiter=";",dtype=float))

X_arr_train = np.loadtxt(sTfx,delimiter=";",dtype=float) 
 
    
print(len(Y_arr_train)," <- len(Y_arr_train)")    
print(len(Y_arr_train[0])," <- len(Y_arr_train[0])")    

print(Y_arr_train[0].shape," <- Y_arr_train[0].shape")
print(X_arr_train.shape," <- X_arr_train.shape")



arr_input_layers = []
arr_of_arr_hidden_layers = []
arr_output_layers = []



# Makes inputs for first level of NN 
for i in range(iNumOfTopNN): 
    arr_input_layers.append(Input(shape=(len(Y_arr_train[0][0]),)))   
    
# Makes Dense layer for first level of NN 
for i in range(iNumOfTopNN): 
    arr_t = []
    for ii in range(i_hidden_layers_num):
        if (ii==0):
            arr_t.append(Dense(i_nn_num, activation='relu')(arr_input_layers[i]))
        else:
            arr_t.append(Dense(i_nn_num, activation='relu')(arr_t[ii-1])) 
    arr_of_arr_hidden_layers.append(arr_t)
    
# Makes outputs for first level of NN 
for i in range(iNumOfTopNN):
    arr_output_layers.append(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(arr_of_arr_hidden_layers[i][len(arr_of_arr_hidden_layers[i])-1]))


# Concatenate outputs
combined_outputs = concatenate(arr_output_layers)

# Makes NN of 2nd level 
hidden_layer2 = Dense(i_nn_2_num, activation='relu')(combined_outputs)
output_layer2 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(hidden_layer2)

model = Model(inputs=arr_input_layers, outputs=output_layer2)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# model.summary()
print("Fit")
hist = model.fit(Y_arr_train, X_arr_train, batch_size=len(Y_arr_train[0]), epochs=20, verbose=1)

python3 -m cProfile -s cumtime slow.py
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
   2856/1    0.007    0.000  120.257  120.257 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.008    0.008  120.257  120.257 slow.py:1(<module>)
3756/1366    0.012    0.000  117.204    0.086 traceback_utils.py:59(error_handler)
386841/9046    0.532    0.000  114.243    0.013 traceback_utils.py:138(error_handler)
        1    0.001    0.001  110.161  110.161 training.py:1455(fit)
       20    0.001    0.000  108.785    5.439 polymorphic_function.py:804(__call__)
       20    0.000    0.000  108.784    5.439 polymorphic_function.py:851(_call)
       27    0.000    0.000   85.008    3.148 tracing_compilation.py:144(trace_function)
       27    0.001    0.000   85.008    3.148 tracing_compilation.py:188(_maybe_define_function)
        5    0.001    0.000   84.758   16.952 tracing_compilation.py:295(_create_concrete_function)
        5    0.005    0.001   83.557   16.711 func_graph.py:920(func_graph_from_py_func)
11308/1068    0.037    0.000   75.711    0.071 api.py:295(converted_call)
11304/1068    0.033    0.000   75.672    0.071 api.py:682(wrapper)
11306/1068    0.016    0.000   75.655    0.071 api.py:449(_call_unconverted)
        5    0.000    0.000   72.978   14.596 polymorphic_function.py:579(wrapped_fn)
        2    0.000    0.000   72.707   36.353 autograph_util.py:38(autograph_handler)
        2    0.000    0.000   72.677   36.338 __autograph_generated_filelgbe8esj.py:8(tf__train_function)
        2    0.000    0.000   72.677   36.338 training.py:1369(step_function)
        2    0.000    0.000   72.658   36.329 distribute_lib.py:1565(run)
        2    0.000    0.000   72.658   36.329 distribute_lib.py:3223(call_for_each_replica)
        2    0.000    0.000   72.658   36.329 distribute_lib.py:4067(_call_for_each_replica)
        2    0.000    0.000   72.658   36.329 training.py:1372(run_step)
        2    0.000    0.000   72.655   36.328 training.py:1121(train_step)
        2    0.000    0.000   65.841   32.920 optimizer.py:522(minimize)
       20    0.001    0.000   64.846    3.242 tracing_compilation.py:125(call_function)
        2    0.000    0.000   62.071   31.036 optimizer.py:1186(apply_gradients)
        2    0.002    0.001   60.617   30.309 optimizer.py:612(apply_gradients)
139519/127253    2.108    0.000   57.672    0.000 op_def_library.py:752(_apply_op_helper)
        2    0.000    0.000   56.923   28.462 optimizer.py:1248(_internal_apply_gradients)
        2    0.000    0.000   56.923   28.462 merge_call_interim.py:29(maybe_merge_call)
        2    0.006    0.003   56.923   28.462 optimizer.py:1333(_distributed_apply_gradients_fn)
8176/4088    0.030    0.000   56.915    0.014 distribute_lib.py:2940(update)
     4090    0.010    0.000   56.893    0.014 distribute_lib.py:3453(merge_call)
     4088    0.011    0.000   56.888    0.014 distribute_lib.py:2882(_replica_ctx_update)
     4090    0.010    0.000   56.542    0.014 distribute_lib.py:3488(_merge_call)
     4088    0.010    0.000   56.123    0.014 distribute_lib.py:2891(merge_fn)
     4088    0.004    0.000   55.743    0.014 distribute_lib.py:4080(_update)
     4088    0.014    0.000   55.739    0.014 distribute_lib.py:4085(_update_non_slot)
     4088    0.005    0.000   55.570    0.014 optimizer.py:1338(apply_grad_to_update_var)
     4088    0.008    0.000   55.565    0.014 optimizer.py:227(_update_step)
     4088    0.119    0.000   55.515    0.014 adam.py:163(update_step)
123047/108287    0.376    0.000   50.722    0.000 dispatch.py:1246(op_dispatch_handler)
        4    0.000    0.000   44.446   11.112 polymorphic_function.py:660(_initialize)
110341/93940    0.134    0.000   37.839    0.000 weak_tensor_ops.py:140(wrapper)
    42936    0.228    0.000   26.884    0.001 math_ops.py:1470(binary_op_wrapper)
       20    0.001    0.000   24.252    1.213 concrete_function.py:1268(_call_flat)
       20    0.002    0.000   24.251    1.213 atomic_function.py:214(call_preflattened)
       20    0.003    0.000   24.249    1.212 atomic_function.py:219(call_flat)
     1042    0.002    0.000   24.216    0.023 execute.py:28(quick_execute)
     1042   24.214    0.023   24.214    0.023 {built-in method tensorflow.python._pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute}
       20    0.000    0.000   24.194    1.210 context.py:1476(call_function)
   188021    0.523    0.000   23.547    0.000 func_graph.py:604(_create_op_internal)
   188021    0.978    0.000   22.564    0.000 ops.py:2593(_create_op_internal)
326723/308315    0.248    0.000   19.491    0.000 trace.py:178(wrapped)
326723/308315    0.198    0.000   19.260    0.000 ops.py:681(convert_to_tensor)
331504/313096    0.462    0.000   19.148    0.000 tensor_conversion_registry.py:164(convert)
139519/127253    1.556    0.000   17.130    0.000 op_def_library.py:411(_ExtractInputsAndAttrs)
      730    0.012    0.000   16.627    0.023 __init__.py:1(<module>)
    30748    0.071    0.000   16.163    0.001 resource_variable_ops.py:629(value)
    30773    0.089    0.000   15.540    0.001 resource_variable_ops.py:791(_read_variable_op)
   188021    1.069    0.000   14.912    0.000 ops.py:1051(from_node_def)
    30773    0.063    0.000   14.912    0.000 resource_variable_ops.py:805(read_and_set_handle)
    30773    0.135    0.000   14.780    0.000 gen_resource_variable_ops.py:511(read_variable_op)
3071/1025    0.046    0.000   13.384    0.013 base_layer.py:1005(__call__)
    17376    0.017    0.000   12.249    0.001 math_ops.py:545(subtract)
    17376    0.063    0.000   12.206    0.001 gen_math_ops.py:12139(sub)
    18484    0.015    0.000   11.511    0.001 resource_variable_ops.py:2339(_dense_var_to_tensor)
    18484    0.021    0.000   11.496    0.001 resource_variable_ops.py:1573(_dense_var_to_tensor)
2659566/1389666    0.952    0.000   11.241    0.000 {built-in method builtins.next}
...

